# Overlapping images JS Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could you guys recommend me a slider that works like in the link bellow?(basically a small image gallery with images that partially overlap each other).

[Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llDtv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sugget spacegallery jQuery plugin

http://www.eyecon.ro/spacegallery/